# How to use XPath preceding-sibling correctly?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm having a trouble selecting preceding siblings. Here's the html:

```
<div>
  <h2>Apple</h2>
  <div class="row">A</div>
  <h2>Banana</h2>
  <div class="row">B</div>
  <h2>Strawberry</h2>
  <div class="row">C</div>
</div>
```

My XPath: `preceding-sibling::h2`.

What I want to do: Select every closest previous `h2` element for every `div.row` .

For example, `div.row A` gives me `Apple h2`, `div.row B` gives me `Banana h2` and `div.row C` gives me `Strawberry h2`.

The problem is my XPath was wrong, it only selected `Apple h2` for every `div.row.`  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select *closest preceding sibling* - just add index `[1]`:

```
preceding-sibling::h2[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

The XPath axis, [`preceding-sibling`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes), contains *all* preceding sibling nodes of the context node.  The XPath, `preceding-sibling::h2`, selects *all* `h2` sibling elements starting from the context node.

Therefore, if the context node is `<div class="row">C</div>` element,

```
/div/div[.="C"]/preceding-sibling::h2
```

selects

```
<h2>Apple</h2>
<h2>Banana</h2>
<h2>Strawberry</h2>
```

Indexing starts nearest the current node, so

```
/div/div[.="C"]/preceding-sibling::h2[1]
```

selects just

```
<h2>Strawberry</h2>
```

and

```
/div/div[.="C"]/preceding-sibling::h2[last()]
```

selects just

```
<h2>Apple</h2>
```

The above examples, of course, would also hold true if you obtained the context node programmatically (rather than as `/div/div[.="C"]` via XPath) and used `preceding-sibling::h2[1]` or `preceding-sibling::h2[last()]` relative to the context node in the hosting language/framework (nokogiri).

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) whichever answer has helped the most.  (Might want to revisit and accept helpful answers to [your past questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758338/%e8%81%96%e6%9d%af%e3%83%84%e3%82%b0%e3%83%9f?tab=questions) as well.) Thanks.