# Why XPath negation not working correctly when preceding the selection?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

I can select a row based on a specific value and then fetch the desired column.
Example: This XPath expression(*Click the Action Button for the student of type Bachelor:*)

```
//td[text()='Bachelor']/following-sibling::td[@class='action']
```

Correctly selects:
[image]

**HTML** 
[image]

I want to select based on negation:  *Click the Action Button for all students that are NOT of type Master*

```
//td[not(text()='Master')]/following-sibling::td[@class='action']
```

But wrongly selects both (only Student's row should be selected):
[image]

Using chrome XPath resolver (f12) for testing for later using the XPath query in Selenium.

Couldn't find any similar example or deep explanation with the research I did.

Comment: I don't see how a path ending with a step `following-sibling::td[@class='action'] ` can select anything but zero or more `td` elements having that `class="action"` attribute. So in which context do you use XPath, have you tried a different implementation, can you show a minimal but complete sample to allow others to reproduce the problem?

Comment: _can select anything but zero or more td elements having that class="action"_  ADDING: 'not to the row that has 'Master'. I am using browser xpath resolver (f12) for Selenium coordinates. Will update in a while the question

Comment: @Ermal There exists a more precise, and less ambiguous solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason

```
//td[not(text()='Master')]/following-sibling::td[@class='action']
```

"selects [`td` elements in] Master row too," as you observe, is that

```
//td[not(text()='Master')]
```

selects all `td` elements that do not have a `text()` node child with a string value of `'Master'`.  Significantly,  that includes all of the predecessor siblings to the `'Master'` `td` that you're trying to exclude, and the problem is that they too have following `td` siblings with `class="action"`.  So, you're not really excluding the row you want to exclude.

To select only the action `td` elements *immediately* preceded by a `td` whose string value is *not* `'Master'`, use this XPath:

```
//td[@class='action'][preceding-sibling::*[1][self::td][not(.='Master')]]
```

Or, you can simply test the row rather than the immediate sibling:

```
//tr[not(td='Master')]/td[@class='action']
```

Note that the former XPath will be sensitive to `td` positioning while the latter XPath will not.

### See also

- [How to use XPath preceding-sibling correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64611111/290085)

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
//td[5][not(. = 'Master])]/following-sibling::td[@class = 'action']
```

or simply:

```
//tr[not(td[5] = 'Master')]/td[@class = 'action']
```

I think it is dangerous to use just `//tr[not(td = 'Master')]` because there could easily be someone with family name `'Master'`